# Automatically switch to explicit function calls in R

Tags: r, r-package

Excuse the odd phrasing of this question... I'm looking for a method / package / tool to automatically go from loading a package and implicitly using calling its functions

```r
library(mypackage)

my_fun(foo = bar)
```

To explicitly calling the function without loading the package

```r
mypackage::my_fun(foo = bar)
```

The use case here is that we write scripts and then later move all / bits of them into functions and possibly into a full package, but it's very time-consuming to add all the `pkg1::`, `pkg2::` bits.

Is there an existing tool or package that can do this automatically? (I couldn't find anything) If not, any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: This is an interesting question and to my knowledge that tool does not yet exist. Here are the bits I imagine you would need to begin. 
1. Scan the file for any `library(...)` calls to make a list of packages used.

2. parse Rscript into a sequence of calls. 3. for each call - walk the namespaces of the packages and determine which package the call comes from. 4. Modify the call and write the file.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I vaguely had in my head but you've put more meat on the bones of the bits I had no idea how to achieve! I have some more things to google now, and see if I can get something working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Justin Landis' comment I had a go myself and now have an ugly but (I think) working function / script to achieve this. I'd welcome any pointers or improvements!

```r
replace_with_explicit <- function(code, packages, comments = FALSE) {
  # Get the functions for each package
  functions <- purrr::map(
    packages,
    function(package) {
      functions <- ls(getNamespaceExports(package))
      functions <- functions[!grepl("[\\[\\|\\$\\<\\+]", functions)]
      return(functions)
    }
  )

  functions <- purrr::set_names(functions, packages)

  replace <- code

  for (package in packages) {
    replace <- stringr::str_replace_all(
      string = replace,
      stringr::regex(
        pattern = paste0("(\\b(?<![:\\.]))((?:", paste(functions[[package]], collapse = "|"), ")\\()"),
        comments = comments),
      replacement = paste0("\\1", package, "::\\2")
    )
  }

  return(replace)
}

# Packages to be replaced - could we grab these from the code?
packages <- c("dplyr", "readr", "haven", "tidyr", "readxl", "glue")

replace_with_explicit(readr::read_lines("NI 1-9.R"), packages)

readr::write_lines(
  replace_with_explicit(readr::read_lines("NI 1-9.R"), packages),
  "NI 1-9.R")
```

Comment: One small improvement I can see immediately: `ls(getNamespace(package))` gives you *all* package names, including non-exported ones. This might cause issues. You can replace it with `getNamespaceExports(package)` to fix that. — Another thing I would do is operate on the R parse tree instead of using string operations. This will reduce false positives (e.g. replacements in strings). But that would make the code a bit more complex.

Comment: Ah, another thing: your code currently only searches for occurences of `functionname(`. This will miss every usage of a function name which isn't directly invoked, such as in `lapply(data, functionname)`.

Comment: That's an issue (`lapply(data, functionname)`) etc. that I hadn't thought of... not sure how I would include that without upping the potential for false positives though?

Comment: You can get dependencies programmatically using the R package funspotr (https://github.com/brshallo/funspotr) and its function `spot_funs()`.